# Very simple HTML / plain-text email not showing at all in microsoft live.com

Tags: php, email, live, html-email

I have been using a very simple PHP function to construct HTML / plain-text emails. It worked well in gmail and many other clients I saw.

As it turns out, @live.com accounts don't get to see the email content at all.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: server@example.com\r\nReply-To: server@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$random_hash\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
//define the body of the message.
$message = "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n" .
    "--$random_hash\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
    //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" .
"\r\nthis is plain text.\r\n\r\n" .
"--$random_hash\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
    //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" .
    "\r\n<html><body>this is wonderful <b>HTML</b> text.</body></html>" .
    "\r\n\r\n--$random_hash--\r\n";
mail('someAddress@live.com', 'This is u umlaut: ü', $message, $headers);
```

If I only send either HTML or plain-text, it will display properly.

Any ideas?

I do not want to use an extra library. All I need the HTML for is links, basically. The answers on [PHP Multi-Part Text/HTML showing blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553903/php-multi-part-text-html-showing-blank) don't help me.

And btw: the u umlaut is displayed incorrectly in the email list in the live.com inbox but displayed correctly when I open the email in live.com...

Comment: look into http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ it works pretty good and has a nice native multipart support

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, ITroubs! However: "I do not want to use an extra library" - I only need HTML to have pretty links because I send out confirmation links with long arbitrary strings that look ugly in plain text. I seriously don't want to introduce dependency on some other code base just for that.

Comment: It really is worth a while trying it out. Those kind of libraries are not made without any reason. There is much knowledge in these libraries regarding handling of special cases and/or special problems. This is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after a few hours.

The issue are the `CR` and `LF`.

I replaced all CRLF (`\r\n`) by LF (`\n`) and it worked.

On the way, I also replaced 7bit by 8bit.

And as for the subject line, that was an easy one to google for, and this is the solution for utf-8:

```
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should properly use a CTE like quoted-printable and encode the data in that; SMTP is still techically a 7-bit protocol, although you can get away with bare 8-bit data in many places these days

Comment: Thank you tripleee. What do you mean by "CTE", how would I "properly use" it?

Comment: Sorry, I mean replace "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" with one of the 7-bit safe encodings for 8-bit data defined by the MIME standard, i.e. either `quoted-printable` or `base64`. For information with just a few odd 8-bit bytes in it, the former is preferred; for binary data or text in a predominantly 8-bit character set, choose the latter. The only difference is in the economy of expression and human readability of the encoded data.

Comment: ... And these are the kinds if things you get to not have to think about if you use a real, designed, documented, tested, supported, debugged, maintained third-party library instead of rolling your own ad-hoc implementation whilst learning about requirements you wish you had never heard about.

Comment: okokok... you guys did a fantastic job. I use phpMailer now. Thanks for challenging my "I don't need anyone else! leave me alone!" attitude...